# How can I open up a jspx in a new window from within a bounded task flow without using dialog framework?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a jspx page within a bounded task flow that has data queried from a ViewObject. I want to present this same data in a different way in a pop-up window. I *DO NOT* want to use the dialog framework in the task flow.

I have tried code like this from within the action method of an `af:commandButton` in a backing bean:

```
ExtendedRenderKitService erks = ExtendedRenderKitService erks =          
Service.getRenderKitService(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),         
ExtendedRenderKitService.class);

erks.addScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), 
"window.open('/myRoot/myPage.jspx');");
```

This opens the window, but I don't have access to the same binding state as the other page; all the binding attributes return null.

How can I get the pop-up to see/use the same binding state as the original page that is in the bounded task flow?

Comment: See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/33-open-page-in-new-tab-169175.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the dialog framework?

How about turning the page into a jsff and including it in a bounded taskflow then adding this taskflow as a region in a pop-up component in your page?

Comment: The goal here is a to create a printer-friendly page. The dialog framework does not print correctly if the page content exceeds one physical page. Similar problem would exist if I used a pop-up component.